# How to sort div dynamically added with data-attribute without reorganize the existent div with the same data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a dynamically added div that looks like this:

```
<div class="pick" id="1" data-costo="1">1</div>
<div class="pick" id="3" data-costo="1">3</div>
<div class="pick" id="0" data-costo="4">4</div>
<div class="pick" id="2" data-costo="6">6</div>
```

inside a "wrapper" div:

```
<div id="mazzo">
</div>
```

the adding function it's like this, after that function the order function will fire

```
for (righe+incrementi;righe+incrementi < 30 ; righe++) {
var container = document.createElement('div'); 
container.id = contatore;   
table.appendChild(container); 
contatore = contatore +1;
```

I have a sorting function that works correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[id^='scelta']").on('click', function sortAll() {
    $("#mazzo").each(function() {
        var items = $(this).children("div").sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(a).data("costo");
        var vB = $(b).data("costo");
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA < vB) ? 0 : 1;
        });
        $(this).append(items);
    });
});
});
```

where [id^='scelta'] is a bunch of div used to trigger the append function for new div in the #mazzo div and then this function will sort correctly all the div at once.

The problem is: if I insert another div  with the same "data-costo" the new div will be placed on top of the existent div. 
For example if I add

```
<div class="pick" id="4" data-costo="1">8</div>
```

the result is this:

```
<div id="mazzo">
**<div class="pick" id="4" data-costo="1">8</div>**
<div class="pick" id="1" data-costo="1">1</div>
<div class="pick" id="3" data-costo="1">3</div>
<div class="pick" id="0" data-costo="4">4</div>
<div class="pick" id="2" data-costo="6">6</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to organize the div so that the existent one is kept in the same position like in the example below?

```
<div id="mazzo">
<div class="pick" id="1" data-costo="1">1</div>
<div class="pick" id="3" data-costo="1">3</div>
**<div class="pick" id="4" data-costo="1">8</div>**
<div class="pick" id="0" data-costo="4">4</div>
<div class="pick" id="2" data-costo="6">6</div>
</div>
```

It's so annoying to see this continuous re-organization...

Comment: You should understand that "id" attributes must be **unique** in a given document. It looks like you use the id "mazzo" over and over.

Comment: How exactly are you adding that div, and shouldn't you call your sort function right after inserting your new div so it get's organized?

Comment: I'm not using the same ID over and over, #mazzo it's the "wrapper" of the inserted div, it's not added every time I add a div, the added div have unique  id (id="0", id="1", id="2" and so on)

Comment: @Lixus the adding function it's like this, after that function the order function will fire
for (righe+incrementi;righe+incrementi < 30 ; righe++) { 
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.className = 'pick';
container.id = contatore; 
table.appendChild(container);
contatore = contatore +1;

Comment: Better if you edit your question and add that code please

Comment: @Lixus Ok tnks, edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another data attribute for `order` and a variable that you can also increment when you add new items.

Then include that `order` in the sort function:

```js
var costos = [1, 4, 6],
  order = 1,
  itemNum = 6,
  $mazzo = $("#mazzo");

function addItem() {
  order++;
  itemNum++;// just for demo display
  var costo = costos[Math.floor(Math.random() * costos.length)];
  var $item = $('<div class="pick">').data({ costo: costo, order: order}).text(itemNum);
  $mazzo.append($item);
  sortMazzo()
}

$('button').click(addItem)

function sortMazzo() {
  var items = $mazzo.children("div").sort(function(a, b) {
    var aData = $(a).data(),
      bData = $(b).data();
    return aData.costo === bData.costo ? aData.order - bData.order : aData.costo - bData.costo;
  });
  $mazzo.append(items)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Add Item
</button>

<div id="mazzo">

  <div class="pick" id="1" data-costo="1" data-order="1">1</div>
  <div class="pick" id="3" data-costo="1" data-order="1">3</div>
  <div class="pick" id="0" data-costo="4" data-order="1">4</div>
  <div class="pick" id="2" data-costo="6" data-order="1">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't think it's what I want achieve, the order of the div must be the data-costo attribute and the snippet will not add new data-costo to the new div. So or I cannot understand you answer (I'm a new to coding)  or this is not what I am looking for. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: If you don't add it then there is no way to sort. Can see how I added it and use that

Comment: I got it! My solution is this:
$("[id^='scelta']").on('click', function sortAll() {
        $("#mazzo").each(function() {
            var items = $(this).children("div").sort(function(a, b) {
            var vA = $(a).data();
            var vB = $(b).data();
            return vA.costo === vB.costo ? vA.id - vB.id : vA.costo - vB.costo;
            });
            $(this).append(items);
        });
    });

Comment: Just another thing, in chrome there's a bug if you sort more than 10 element, how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the bug? create demo that reproduces it

Comment: The function works correctly on all browser BUT (on chrome), if you have more than 10 element to reorder it's a mess! I've find this statement on a similar question: You need the "? 1 : -1" because of a bug in Chrome, without this it won't sort more than 10 divs! http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/14-Sorting-Were-Doing-It-Wrong.html